# unable to open spreadsheets with Zend_Gdata?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-gdata, google-sheets-api

```
<?php
include('Zend/Gdata.php');
include('Zend/Gdata/Spreadsheets.php');
include('Zend/Gdata/ClientLogin.php');


$service = Zend_Gdata_Spreadsheets::AUTH_SERVICE_NAME;
$client = Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin::getHttpClient('myemail@gmail.com', 'password', $service);
$spreadsheetService = new Zend_Gdata_Spreadsheets($client);
$sheets = $spreadsheetService->getSpreadsheetFeed();
foreach ($sheets as $sheet) {
    //echo get_class($sheet) . '<br>'; exit;
    echo $sheet->getContent() . '<br>';
    echo $sheet->getId() . '<br>';

    $query = new Zend_Gdata_Spreadsheets_DocumentQuery();
    $query->setSpreadsheetKey($sheet->getId());
    $feed = $spreadsheetService->getWorksheetFeed($query);
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($feed); exit;
}
```

Here's the error I get when I do that:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Gdata_App_HttpException' with message 'Expected response code 200, got 400 Invalid request URI'
```

That doesn't make a lot of sense to me.  If they spreadsheet key was invalid why would $sheet->getId() be returning it?

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** Have updated this to make it more in line with what I think you want - let me know if it's off the mark but this may help.  I'm assuming you're using an MVC pattern with Zend Framework so you may need to tweak accordingly otherwise
Try this class:

```
class SpreadsheetAdapter
{
    protected $_spreadsheetService;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $client = 
            Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin::getHttpClient($yourUsername,$yourPassword,
                Zend_Gdata_Spreadsheets::AUTH_SERVICE_NAME);

        $this->_spreadsheetService = new Zend_Gdata_Spreadsheets($client);
    }

    public function getSheets()
    {
        $sheetArray = array();
        $totalSheets = count($this->_spreadsheetService->getSpreadsheetFeed()->entries[0]->link);

        for($i = 0; $i <= $totalSheets; $i++)
        {
            $link{$i} = $this->_spreadsheetService->getSpreadsheetFeed()->entries[$i]->link[1]->href;
            $title{$i} = $this->_spreadsheetService->getSpreadsheetFeed()->entries[$i]->getTitleValue();
            $sheetArray[$link{$i}] = $title{$i};
        }

        return $sheetArray; 
    }

    public function getRows($spreadsheetKey)
    {
        // returns a multidimensional array filled with data from populated rows in a Google Docs Spreadsheet
        $query = new Zend_Gdata_Spreadsheets_DocumentQuery();
        $query->setSpreadsheetKey($spreadsheetKey);
        $feed = $this->_spreadsheetService->getWorksheetFeed($query);
        return $feed->entries[0]->getContentsAsRows();
    }

}
```

Then this in your chosen controller:

```
public function spreadAction()
{
    $adapter = new SpreadsheetAdapter();
    $sheetArray = $adapter->getSheets();
    $this->view->sheetArray = $sheetArray;      
}
```

Then this in your view:

```
<h2>Spreadsheets</h2>
<ul>
<?php 
foreach($this->sheetArray as $sheet['link'] => $sheet['title'])
{
    echo '<li><a href="' . $sheet['link'] . '">' . $sheet['title'] . '</a></li>';
}

?>
</ul>
```

**NOTE:** While there are probably other ways of doing this you could get hold of just the spreadsheet key by using something like this (I've just modified what would be in the view):

```
<h2>Spreadsheets</h2>
<ul>
<?php 
foreach($this->sheetArray as $sheet['link'] => $sheet['title'])
{
    $linkChop = explode('=',$sheet['link']);
    $spreadsheetKey = end($linkChop);
    echo '<li><a href="http://yourdomain/yourmodule/yourcontroller/youraction/' . $spreadsheetKey . '">' . $sheet['title'] . '</a></li>';
}

?>
</ul>
```

In the above example I was trying to illustrate how you might use just the key. If I was doing this in ZF myself I'd bind $spreadsheetKey as a parameter in the url when routing to an action where I'd want to use a method such as getRows(). If you want an example I could put one together?

Appreciate I'm guessing a bit as to what you want to achieve but hopefully this helps.

Cheers,

Dave

**ABOUT 2 STEP AUTH:** Something slightly off topic which may be helpful is to make sure 2-step authentication is turned off on the Google account as it will stop you from connecting this way.

Comment: Also note if you aren't using Zend Framework you'll need to do your includes like before

Comment: I still get the same thing.  My code:  http://paste2.org/p/1884518 I'm not using two factor authentication for this account either.  If I was using two factor authentication not even $sheet->getId() would work.

Comment: Hi, I've got a few things I'd like to try (I'm able to get access to a feed at the moment) so I'll give them a go and get back to you a bit later on.  If you get a solution in the meantime just let me know. Cheers, Dave